# How to reduced the size of wlapp in IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

i want to compress the size of wlapp of my android version.
current size is 35.5 MB

i have done following changes in application-descriptor.xml and re-deploy it but 
size is not getting reduced

```
<android version="1.0">
        <worklightSettings include="false"/>
        <security>
            <encryptWebResources enabled="false"/>
            <testWebResourcesChecksum enabled="false" ignoreFileExtensions="png, jpg, jpeg, gif, mp4, mp3"/>
            <publicSigningKey/>
            <packageName/>
        </security>
        <compressWebResources enabled="true"/>
    </android>
```

is there any other way to compress it as i have to deploy it on client server?

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to improve the question's description?

1. Are you really talking about the .wlapp that you deploy to the MobileFirst Server, or
2. Are you referring to the .apk file that you install in the physical Android device?

---

Note that the `compressWebResources` opiton is only relevant to Worklight 5.0.6 and is *no longer used* in later releases.

Since you are using MobileFirst Platform Foundation 7.0 (based on other questions by you), you can try the following methods to possibly help reduce the Android application's file size (the .apk file, not .wlapp file):

1. You should also remove any unused code and libraries from the project as well as generate images in appropriate file sizes
2. If using 3rd party libraries check if there are minified versions of them
3. Enable concatenation and minification: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/c_optimizing_apps_build_settings.html
4. Enable Android Proguard: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.deploy.doc/admin/c_pg_obfus_intro.html

You should also extract the generated .apk file (it's basically a .zip) and check which files exactly add to the application file size, and attempt the above options based on the result.

Note that the .wlapp file is made up *only* from your application web resources, so that means that whatever you are using in your app, is what causing the large file size of the .wlapp file. You need to check that.